# Sum list of list elements in python like sql group by

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists (string,integer)

eg:

```
my_list=[["apple",5],["banana",6],["orange",6],["banana",9],["orange",3],["apple",111]]
```

I'd like to sum the same items and finally get this:

```
my2_list=[["apple",116],["banana",15],["orange",9]]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on the *sorted* list:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list=[["apple",5],["banana",6],["orange",6],["banana",9],["orange",3],["apple",111]]

my_list2 = []
for i, g in groupby(sorted(my_list), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    my_list2.append([i, sum(v[1] for v in g)])

print(my_list2)
# [['apple', 116], ['banana', 15], ['orange', 9]]
```

---

Speaking of SQL *Group By* and *pre-sorting*:

> The operation of `groupby()` is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It
>   generates a break or new **group** every time the value of the key
>   function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have **sorted**
>   the data using the same key function). That behavior **differs** from
>   SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their
>   input order.

*Emphasis Mine*

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list= [["apple",5],["banana",6],["orange",6],["banana",9],["orange",3],["apple",111]]

result = defaultdict(int)
for fruit, value in my_list:
    result[fruit] += value
result = result.items()

print result
```

Or you can keep result as dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Using Pandas and `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['fruit', 'count']).groupby('fruit').sum()
        count
fruit        
apple     116
banana     15
orange      9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
[[k, sum(v for _, v in g)] for k, g in groupby(sorted(my_list), key = lambda x: x[0])]

# [['apple', 116], ['banana', 15], ['orange', 9]]
```

Comment: You don't need to `sort` on a key

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It seems to work as such but can't find any doc that confirms it will sort by the first element of the sublists.

Comment: When a sort key is not provided, the elements are compared directly: `['a', 2] < ['b', 5] -> True`. And I think it is sufficient for sorting to bring similar items together as neighbours since the order in this case is not really needed

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Excellent point. After having a look at how lists are compared, it makes perfect sense now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the order to preserved, then plz use the below code.

```
my_list=[["apple",5],["banana",6],["orange",6],["banana",9],["orange",3],["apple",111]]
my_dict1 = {}

for d in my_list:
   if d[0] in my_dict1.keys():
      my_dict1[d[0]] += d[1]
   else:
      my_dict1[d[0]] = d[1]

my_list2 = [[k,v] for (k,v) in my_dict1.items()]
```