# sum list object value with same code in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python, I have faced some problem. I have an object list like this :

```
[  
    {  
        'balance':-32399.0,
        'code':u'1011',
        'name':u'Stock Valuation Account'
    },
    {  
        'balance':-143503.34,
        'code':u'1011',
        'name':u'Stock Interim Account (Received)'
    },
    {  
        'balance':117924.2499995,
        'code':u'1011',
        'name':u'Stock Interim Account (Delivered)'
    },
    {  
        'balance':-3500000.0,
        'code':u'1101',
        'name':u'Cash'
    },
    {  
        'balance':-50000.0,
        'code':u'1101',
        'name':u'Other Cash'
    },
]
```

I need to sum it based on the code, so the result will be.

```
[  
    {  
        'balance':6819,91,
        'code':u'1011',
    },
    {  
        'balance':-3550000.0,
        'code':u'1101',
    },
]
```

have search over StackOverflow, but still not got what I need.
any help?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum list of list elements in python like sql group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647928/sum-list-of-list-elements-in-python-like-sql-group-by)

Comment: Tip: use Google to search StackOverflow instead of the built-in search engine (unless searching for tags).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog already read that answer, I am still new, so don't know if sum value on an object with key inside the array. on your mentioned that sum on array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, using `groupby` and `sum` within some `comprehensions`:
As said in the comments, for using groupby the list need to be presorted.
In addition you can use `operator.attrgetter` instead of lambdas in the `key` parameters of `sorted` and `groupby`.

```
l = [  
    {  
        'balance':-32399.0,
        'code':u'1011',
        'name':u'Stock Valuation Account'
    },
    ...
]

from itertools import groupby
import operator 

selector_func = operator.attrgetter("code")
l = sorted(l, key=selector_func)
result = [{"code" : code, "balance" : sum(x["balance"] for x in values)} for code, values in groupby(l, selector_func)]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'code': '1011', 'balance': -57978.0900005}, {'code': '1101', 'balance': -3550000.0}]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/CuteQuaintWebsites)

Comment: Would help to remind OP that `groupby` requires the items to be pre-sorted by the key.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an oneliner without any import :

```
a = ...
result = [{'balance' : sum([i['balance'] for i in a if i['code']==j]), 'code' : j} for j in set([k['code'] for k in a])]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[{'balance': -3550000.0, 'code': '1101'}, {'balance': -57978.0900005, 'code': '1011'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
    {
        'balance':-32399.0,
        'code':u'1011',
        'name':u'Stock Valuation Account'
    },
    ...
]
d = {}
for entry in data:
    d[entry['code']] = d.get(entry['code'],0) + entry['balance']
print([{'balance':b,'code':c} for c,b in d.items()])
```

Would print:

```
[{'balance': -57978.0900005, 'code': '1011'}, {'balance': -3550000.0, 'code': '1101'}]
```